# DataGrip wrap text inside cell

Tags: datagrip

How to wrap the text inside cell in DataGrip?

[image: datagrip cell]

I am increasing my row height and want the text/data in value column to wrap instead of me scrolling to the right to view all the cell content.
Is it possible to do in Datagrip?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Choose 'Active Editor: Use Soft Wraps' from the Find Action (Ctrl+Shift+A) menu if you'd like to have word wraps for viewing the text.

[image]

Comment: 2018.2.2. Why? Can you describe?

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work either (Using 2018.2.2). Setting 'Active Editor: Use Soft Wraps' to 'ON' only enables wrapping in the 'Edit' mode of the grid output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBnRs.png My interpretation of the author's inquiry was about how to get the text to wrap just in the grid output (without double-clicking into 'edit' mode) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpsar.png

Comment: Ah, got it. Makes sense! Here is the ticket which I think is about it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-1951

Comment: @moscas does the 'ticket' makes it do what author asked? JetBrains has this crazy style of offering tickets as their solution to various issues. If it doesn't do, don't shove ticket, because nobody solves those tickets.